# Splunk generate a random events

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I'm a rookie in Splunk. I am using it for the first time.
I noticed that if the interval value is 60, it generates 2 events every minute.

This confused me. Is it a known situation?

Comment: Splunk does not generate events unless you are using the EventGen app (which may not be supported any longer).  Please be more specific about your Splunk environment, the data you are onboarding, and the search(es) you are running.  Where are you seeing the "interval"?

Answer (score 0):

if to generate random events, you could go for :

|makeresults

command. Such that:

```
 | makeresults count=100 | eval class=if((random()%5) == 1, "class A", "class B")
```